# For loops in Mathematica

Tags: programming

I'm actually the first time using loops in *Mathematica*. For example, I have:

```
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
 For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, ....]
```

How it is possible now to loop only over i≠j ?

Best regards

Comment: `n = 5;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
  If[i != j ,
   Print["i=", i, " j=", j]
   ]
  ]
 ]` screen shot to confirm the result ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/suInp.png)

Comment: `Do[If[i != j, ...], {i, n}, {j, n}]`.  If you're a beginner, try to avoid `For` in favour of functional constructs and `Do`.

Comment: `Do[..., {i, n}, {j, Drop[Range[n], {i}]}]` is an alternative.

Comment: To close-voters: It seems to me that the answer to the main question of how to skip `i == j` is not easily deduced from the cited duplicate. It may not be a very deep question but it does have at least one efficient solution peculiar to *Mathematica* (and perhaps others) that is not the standard Fortran/C/Java solution.

Answer (score 4):

In *Mathematica* you can iterate over `i != j` with

```
Do[<code>, {i, n}, {j, Drop[Range[n], {i}]}]
```

In a sense it really does the actual iteration desired.  The following iterates over all pairs `{i, j}`, although `<code>` is executed only for `i != j`.

```
Do[If[i != j, <code>], {i, n}, {j, n}]
```

The difference in speed is minimal but measurable:

```
With[{n = 2000},
  Do[1, {i, n}, {j, Drop[Range[n], {i}]}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.216874, Null}  *)

With[{n = 2000},
  Do[If[i != j, 1], {i, n}, {j, n}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.202791, Null}  *)
```

It may seem like a lot, but the execute time of `<code>` is likely to be an order of magnitude larger at least.

To save a couple of milliseconds over the first loop, there's this:

```
With[{n = 2000},
 With[{r = Range[n]},
   Do[1, {i, n}, {j, Drop[r, {i}]}]
   ]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.210090, Null}  *)
```

A very small, but seemingly persistent advantage, even with `` GeneralUtilities`AccurateTiming ``.